# Fedora 17 - Can't access remote machine using hostname

Tags: linux, networking, fedora, hostname

I am using Fedora 17 and am trying to access a remote machine (running Fedora 15) using its hostname which isn't working. The machine is right next to me on the same switch as my machine (so they are both on the same network with the same subnet and everything). When I was running Windows (7 32-bit) on my machine I could access the other machine no problem but now that I am running Fedora 17 that's not the case. Is there an additional daemon or something that I need to be using in order for this to work?

Comment: Do you have dns set up on the fedora machine?

Comment: Both machines should be using the company's internal DNS servers but that is a good point. I will check to make sure this is the case when I am in there tomorrow. What you said made me realize that I need to check a few more things since I am no longer tied to their AD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being an internal specific issue. It had to do with the way our network at work was setup and how both of my Linux machines weren't on the domain. Everything has been resolved now!

Answer (score 0):

Some questions.

Can you resolve any external site from the F17 system.

If yes, then can you ping the F15 system by ip and then by hostname. Collect 5 iterations and pastebin please.

If it is working with ip but not with hostname, can you add the hostname and ip address of the F15 system into the /etc/hosts file and then try pinging. Please ensure the proper syntax is followed.

If still not pinging, I would rather see tcpdump.
tcpdump -s0 -i ethX -w /tmp/tcpdump_hostname.pcap host

If still can't find anything, then I will compare with tcpdump with IP address ping working.

Obviously, I expect you have checked the interface configuration files first and they are working.

Comment: I can resolve anything internally and externally by IP (including the F15 system). I'm going to check on a few things tomorrow when I have access to the machines since I just remembered I am no longer tied to the AD at work. If everything checks out I will get back to you.